# How to query a Room database so it returns a single object?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I'm using Room as my local database for my project. I have created a `MovieDao` interface:

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY title ASC")
    LiveData<List<Movies.Movie>> getMovies();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<Movies.Movie> getMovie(int id);
}
```

Everytime I try to call `getMovies()` method, it correctly return a list of `Movie` objects but if I call `getMovie(int id)` and pass an id that exist for sure in the database I always get NPE.

Hoe can I create a query than can return a single `Movie` object?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
LiveData<Movies.Movie> liveData = movieRepository.retrieveFavoriteMovieTask(550);
liveData.observe(this, m -> {
    Log.d(TAG, m.title);
});
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.myapp.Movies$Movie.title' on a null object reference

Comment: that query looks fine. could you add the stack-trace?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sure, right away.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Please check now.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Any idea?

Comment: `m` is not defined within the scope; that probably  should be `movie.title`.

Comment: Sorry it was `m`, my mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

id may be reserved by room. You can set a auto incrementing PK with @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) then define your own id (movie_id) that you can set and get at will while leaving the PK integrity intact.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ok, I understand, is the same format but how can I query to get only one object? The one which has the id equal to a specific id.

Comment: SELECT movie_title From movies where.... where movie_title is whatever field you want back. Select * is giving you the entire row

Comment: Ok and will return me the `movie_title` as a String or the entire movie bject?

Comment: should be a string or whatever the field is set to in your entity class.

Comment: Ok but I don't want to query only the `movie_title`, I want to get the entire Movie object which has a specific id. Do you think that it can be done?

Comment: Then i would mirror the return function of the first query. Change LiveData<Movies.Movie> getMovie(int id); to LiveData<List<Movies.Movie>> getMovies();

Comment: Just did and the list has size 0 :( No `Movie` object in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187679/discussion-between-notsileous-and-ioana-p).

Comment: Yes, that was it. The id was the issue. I have changed the query instead of id to use the title and it return the correct Movie object. So **`id`** is somehow reserved. Please edit your question so I can accept it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: `id` is not reserved (and it would be pretty annoying if that were the case). I use it over and over. just `_id` is used by Sqlite. and that query returns; only the `Log` statement refers to a non-existent variable.